# Getting 404 Error When Rewriting URLs with .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, clean-urls

I am trying to rewrite my URLs to have clean URLs. For example I want the following URL rewritten like so:

`www.domain.com/events/events.php`

`www.domain.com/events/`

It is rewritting the URL correctly but the rewritten URL is giving a 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

I am using the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)/(.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/%3/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've got the rules to *externally redirect the browser*, you then need to add rules to *internally rewrite to the actual files*. So you need to add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$1.php [L]
```

Now, this rule takes a URI that looks like `/(something)/` to `/(something)/(something).php`. So:

- `/foo/` to `/foo/foo.php`
- `/example/` to `/example/example.php`

etc.

There's no other info you're providing in the rewritten URI that tells you what the php filename is, so if you have something like this:

- `/foo/bar.php`

there's no way to extract the "bar" out of `/foo/`. You'd need to additionally encode that in the clean url:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)/(.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just had a question though..from the research I did about rewriting URLs, I thought that when you rewrite URLs it only affects how that URL is displayed in the browser but in the backend it is still accessing the original URL. Is that correct? And if so then why was it giving me the 404?

Comment: @AngeloRodriguez No, rewriting happens on the server's end, when you change what URL is displayed, you're *redirecting* the browser, the browser then re-requests the new URL.

Comment: I am using the following rules, but the URL www.nightlinx.com/events/miami does not load the content of the page. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)?$ /events/events.php?location=$1 [L]